# Error while running procedure without parameter: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have this update statement in oracle procedure

Spec:

```
PROCEDURE Update_G;
```

Body:

```
PROCEDURE Update_G
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE group SET check_flag = 0 WHERE check_flag = 1;
  UPDATE employee SET check_flag = 0 WHERE check_flag = 1;
END Update_G;
```

This procedure when i call from .net its throwing error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to Update_G
```

It runs from oracle but from .net its throwing error. If input parameter is added it works, but i don't need any parameter.

Dot Net Code:

```
Database db = GetOracleDbInstance(); 
object[] spParams = new object[0]; 
string spName = "Update_G"; 
db.ExecuteDataSet(spName, spParams);
```

//There are no parameters here, i also tried this:

```
Database db = GetOracleDbInstance(); 
db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Update_G");
```

Comment: give use the signiture for the procedure you are calling not the body only !  i mean the arguments and if you provide the full scipt of it would be better along with how you call it in .net code to see the registered parameters is like the oracle procedure in number and type

Comment: Dot Net Code:
Database db = GetOracleDbInstance();
object[] spParams = new object[0];
string spName = "Update_G";
db.ExecuteDataSet(spName, spParams);

There are no parameters here, i also tried this:
Database db = GetOracleDbInstance();
                db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Update_G");

Comment: @Aditya, Don't put the code examples in a comment. Edit your question and add them there

Comment: What is the `Database` class ? is it this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx ?

Comment: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary

Comment: .NET what language C# VB etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

**//parameters required for procedure,if no parameter then pass Null**

```
Database db = GetOracleDbInstance(); 

string spName = "Update_G"; 
db.ExecuteDataSet(spName, Null); //or db.ExecuteDataSet(spName); try both
```

[answer reference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29205-Access-any-Stored-Procedure-with-or-without.aspx)

Comment: spParams= Null; throws an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Aditya i will do some search and get back to yuo